# How to pass arguments to mySQL query with php

Tags: php, mysql, variables, quote

I am trying to create a dynamic page to soft-delete record from various tables.

Can anyone help me to fix the following statement? I am so confused to the quotes when it comes to variables:

```
$table_name = $_REQUEST['t'];
$record_id = $_POST['rid'];
$field_id = print_var_name($rid);

$sql="UPDATE `$table_name` SET `is_delete` = 1 WHERE `$field_id` = '$record_id'";
```

Comment: i can't see any syntax error in the sql. all I know is it is vulnerable with sql injection.

Comment: Whatever you have typed here looks perfect and right to me

Comment: Thanks JW. I am just a beginner. These codes are only for password protected admin panel. I will learn hard to avoid sql injection through PDO but that's too advanced for me at this time. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in this way.

```
$sql="UPDATE `" . $table_name . "` SET `is_delete` = 1 WHERE `" . $field_id . "` = '$record_id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
 $table_name = $_REQUEST['t'];
    $record_id = $_POST['rid'];
    $field_id = print_var_name($rid);

    $sql="UPDATE ".$table_name." SET ". is_delete." = 1 WHERE " .$field_id. " =" .$record_id;
```

Or change your query like this.

```
  $sql="DELETE FROM ".$table_name." WHERE ".$field_id. "=".$record_id;
```

Comment: the OP wants **soft delete**.